# Boundary Point of Subdifferential as the Limit of a Sequence of Gradients

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, subgradient

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open convex set. Let $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. We know that $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere. The subdifferential of $f$ at $x\in\Omega$ is defined as
$$
\partial f(x)=\{g\in\mathbb{R}^n:f(y)\ge f(x)+g^T(y-x)\ \forall\,y\in\Omega\}.
$$

**My question:** Is it true that for every $x\in\Omega$, for every boundary point $g$ of $\partial f(x)$, there always exists a sequence $\{x_n\}\subset\Omega$ such that $f$ is differentiable at each $x_n$, $x_n\to x$, and $\nabla f(x_n)\to g$?

**My attempt:**

1. This is not true for general $g\in\partial f(x)$. For example, in $\mathbb{R}$, the convex function $f(x)=|x|$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}\backslash{\{0\}}$ and $\partial f(0)=[-1,1]$. Since $f'(y)\in\{-1,1\}$ for all $y\neq 0$, then there does not exist $\{x_n\}\subset\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ such that $x_n\to 0$ and $\nabla f(x_n)\to 0\in\partial f(0)$.
2. I believe the statement is true at least in the speical case of $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\partial f(x)\subset\mathbb{R}$ is closed and convex, then it must be an interval. So I suppose it should be true that
   $$
   \partial f(x)=\left[\liminf_{y\to x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x},\limsup_{y\to x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\right].
   $$
   This should help prove the statement.

I am a beginner in convex analysis. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to find the answer to this question?

Comment: @Vcwh No I haven't.

Comment: I think could be true, but I was working in this stuff time ago, I don't remember the possible details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or higher dimensional space. Think of the function $f(x,y)=\max\{|x|,|y|\}$ at $(0,0)$. The best one can show is that there ***exist*** certain type of boundary points $g$ of $\partial f(x)$ such that $\nabla f(x_n)\to g$ where $x_n\to x$ and $f$ is differentiable at each $x_n$. This type of boundary points is exactly the extreme points of the closed convex set $\partial f(x)$.

In fact, a widely known result for locally Lipschitz function is given by Theorem 2.5.1 in this [book](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611971309). It basically tells us that even if not every point in $\partial f(x)$ is the limit of a sequence $\nabla f(x_n)$ with $f$ differentiable at $x_n$, it is indeed a convex combination of the limits of such sequences.